# Depending on browser width let fancybox do its work or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, width

I want to check each time the width of the window (even on browser resize). This is my function:

```
function checkWidth() {
    var width =  $(window).width()
    if(width > 640){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
            alert(width);
}
if(checkWidth()){
    $(function(){
        $("#fancylink").fancybox({
            'type': 'iframe',
            'width': 900,
            'height': 600,
            'autoScale': false
        }); 
    });
}
```

But the width is checked only once. The reason is I think that my query is on the outer side and therefore only checked on page load. How can I restructure my code?

**Edit:**

`fancybox` is instantiated on the element with the id `fancylink`. In this case it is an anchor element with a certain URL. This URL is opened as iFrame in the fancybox if someone clicks on the link. My goal is to not open the fancybox if a certain width is not reached. Instead it should act as normal link and open in a new tab. Only when the width is e.g. more than 640px than it should open in a fancybox as iFrame.

So I would have to check the browser width on browser resize or if device orientation changes from portrait to landscape. In my code `fancybox` will be instantiated if at page load the width is reached or not. But if device orientation changes or browser resizes this doesn't work anymore. Is there a solution for this?

I think I'll leave it as it is because I don't know any other solution for my problem.

Comment: What you need is to fire the function on an event every time the window changes size, like : `$(window).on('resize', function() {...})`

Comment: @adeneo: I don't think you got my problem. I want to offer an additional functionality if the window size is big enough. So ` $("#fancylink").fancybox({` should only be executed if window size is big enough. Otherwise it should not be executed.

Comment: Then you need to set the value of whatever variable you are checking inside a resize function, otherwise it won't be updated with the window's actual size.

Comment: fancybox is here instantiated. In a resize function I would need to instantiate or destroy the instance at runtime. I don't know if that is the solution. I only want to prohibit fancybox from execution if a min. device width is not reached.

Answer (score 3):

You should set an event listener for window resizing:

```
var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;

window.onresize = function() {
  windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
  // do something with the new width
};
```

Comment: Note: jQuery has the `.resize` method for this - [docs](http://api.jquery.com/resize/).

Comment: +1 for non-jQuery version. But this `object.attachEvent ("onresize", handler);` would have been better I think. EDIT: ah, FF, `object.addEventListener ("resize", handler, useCapture);`

Comment: You don't have to use the jQuery method here. It works with plain javascript, too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind it to window's `resize` event.

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    checkWidth();
});
​
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've ever attached an event handler to the window's resize event, you have probably noticed that while Firefox fires the event slow and sensibly, IE and Webkit go totally spastic.

```
(function($,sr){

  // debouncing function from John Hann
  // http://unscriptable.com/index.php/2009/03/20/debouncing-javascript-methods/
  var debounce = function (func, threshold, execAsap) {
      var timeout;

      return function debounced () {
          var obj = this, args = arguments;
          function delayed () {
              if (!execAsap)
                  func.apply(obj, args);
              timeout = null; 
          };

          if (timeout)
              clearTimeout(timeout);
          else if (execAsap)
              func.apply(obj, args);

          timeout = setTimeout(delayed, threshold || 100); 
      };
  }
    // smartresize 
    jQuery.fn[sr] = function(fn){  return fn ? this.bind('resize', debounce(fn)) : this.trigger(sr); };

})(jQuery,'smartresize');


// usage:
$(window).smartresize(function(){  
    checkWidth();
});
```

Reference : http://paulirish.com/2009/throttled-smartresize-jquery-event-handler/